# stored array data access

Tags: php

I'd like to create a function where i could fill a table with data accessed from a url. For example "urlexample.php"

Comment: There's an example here: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/ and you can reference jquery's API as well: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the jquery `$.getJSON()` function to return JSON data from a remote location.  Here is an example using dummy data from here: http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos

```
const tableBody = $('#tblExample>tbody');

$.getJSON('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos', function(data) {
  //iterate over each json object in the json collection returned from the server
  //value represents each individual object
  //you can access the properties on the 'value' object using dot notation
  $.each(data, function(key, value) {
    //create a <tr/> object for your table
    let row = $('<tr/>');
//set row values
    $('<td/>', {html: value.title}).appendTo(row);
    $('<td/>', {html: value.url}).appendTo(row);
    row.appendTo(tableBody);
  });
});
```

And the HTML:

```
<table id="tblExample">
  <thead>
     <th>Title</th><th>Url</>
  </thead>
  <tbody/>
</table>
```

You can see a working example here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WoZVG

Comment: Hmm i can see now the approach to it , thank you! However the page im trying to access is very much presented in a different form,  an actual example {"id":"247963","business":"biz","address"close by","rating":"2","date":"2013-14-05","postcode":"213req"} , so its like in an array but not clearly laid out like the example link above. can this be changed or is there another way to access this?

Comment: Updated by answer with a few comments.  You should be able to translate the example data to your use case pretty easily.  (ie. value.business)

Comment: Well i changed around the values to match the in table values , however im still not receiving the data back? Ive updated the code above so you can see what i have

Comment: @randomwhiteguy Heres a code pen using your exact data: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WoZVGQ  -- most likely your table id is incorrect?

Comment: it works fine in codepen , but not in notepad++, no table id and everything seems correct

Comment: @randomwhiteguy -- sorry man -- This is working on my desktop (in notepad++) as well. Most likely you've got a typo somewhere.

Comment: I've uploaded my current code, i checked it , dont think there are any errors.. does it matter if its saved as a php or html file?

Comment: @randomwhiteguy you've got two problems: (1) your `<script src="..."></script>` needs to be it's own block (2) Wrap your javascript in it's own `<script></script>` block and move it right above the closing body tag. Also, this is really like 5 different questions at this point.  Please consider breaking this up next time.

Comment: Well looks like I've got  a lot of learning to do! ajax/jquery is all new to me. Thank you so much , its working ! I'm also new to stackoverflow, so sorry about that!